# WHERE clause returning mixed results + Grouping weekly data by quarter

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2014

I've got two questions:

1) A WHERE clause is not working consistently? 
2) I'd like to know who to group weekly data into quarterly data.

1) I've got a WHERE clause in some code that is not filtering the results I want by the SubCategory selected.

I tested the WHERE clause on shorter code (below) and it gave the top 10 results in the Yogurt SubCategory from the Enterprise Structure View, as expected.

```
select top 10 * from v_EnterpriseStructure
where SubCategoryName = 'Yogurt'
```

However, when I ran this code, which returns Price Zone ID, Price Zone Name, Client Department ID, etc, it returns the data for all SubCategories, instead of JUST Yogurt. Does anyone know why this could be?

```
select
    pz.PriceZoneID,
    pz.Name,
    es.ClientDepartmentID,
    es.DepartmentName,
    es.ClientCategoryID,
    es.CategoryName,
    es.ClientSubCategoryID,
    es.SubCategoryName,
    es.ClientProductID,
    es.ProductName,
    ash.Sales as Units, 
    ash.price * ash.Sales as CashSales, 
    ash.Cost, 
    CAST(ash.date as Date) as Date 
from aggregatedsaleshistory as ash 
join v_EnterpriseStructure as es on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID
join PriceZone as pz on pz.PriceZoneID = ash.PriceZoneID 
WHERE es.SubCategoryName = 'Yogurt' 
GROUP BY 
    pz.PriceZoneID,
    pz.Name,
    es.ClientDepartmentID,
    es.DepartmentName,
    es.ClientCategoryID,
    es.CategoryName,
    es.ClientSubCategoryID,
    es.SubCategoryName,
    es.ClientProductID,
    es.ProductName,
    ash.Cost,
    ash.Date
```

2) I'd posted a question about this last week, along with a question about why some code wasnt working.

Although the question about why the code wasn't working was answered, the question about grouping the data into quarters wasn't quite answered.

With the quarterly question, I'd like to return the results from the data the long query in Q1 above returns (currently in weekly format, as the dates are all weekly dates) into quarterly format.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data, table structure and expected results would be very helpful here...

Comment: If v_EnterpriseStructure  es  is a view, that may be the issue, would have to post the query for that as you are using the SubCategoryName from that (you tested just that query) but are you sure the ProductSID is correct/matching what you need to do the join properly (The IDs being returned may not be correct/matching to give what you want)

Comment: If you remove the [group by] do you still get unexpected ClientDepartmentID? I don't think this would happen unless the data is not structured the way you think it is. You can audit one of the strange rows and individually select the three tables using the ID in your join clauses to get a good picture of the data.

Comment: Posting broken query without providing description of what you're trying accomplish won't help us help you.  Describe what you want to do.  Provide sample input, expected output, table structure/relationship.